# Calculating the complex signal's average power

Tags: periodic, signal-power

$$x(t) = \cos(\pi i t/20+\pi/4) - 2je^{j \,12\pi i t} + 5\sin(2\pi i t/3+\pi/3) $$

I need to find the signal's average power.
How can I do that? 
The $i$ index (represented in red in the below image) just denotes a random integer.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Solve the integral:
$$
P = \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} |x(t)|^2 dt
$$
This is usually unwieldy to solve directly; it can be shown that if a signal is periodic, you only need to integrate over the fundamental period $T_0$:
$$
P = \frac{1}{T_0}\int_{-T_0/2}^{T_0/2} |x(t)|^2 dt
$$

EDIT:

Another "trick" is to note that sinusoidal signals of different frequencies are [incoherent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(physics)), so when integrating over long periods of time, it is only necessary to find the power of the individual components because the cross terms go to zero.

This means that
$$
P = P_1 + P_2 + P_3
$$
assuming $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are incoherent.  Find the individual powers and sum them.

Comment: Waht do I need to do with the exp() component  in the absolute value ?

Comment: @ShlomiShabtai think closely, what is $|e^{j\phi}|$ for absolutely arbitrary $\phi$?

Comment: yeah i know but it's an absolute value of a sum and it's not the same as sum of absolute values. Is there another way to break it up that i can't see ?

Comment: yes, read my comment closely; you seem to respond to something I didn't write.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: yes, but you seemed to respond to something he didn't ask

Comment: I don't think so :) $|x|=\sqrt{x\cdot x^*}$, so to calculate all this, you'd build products between the terms in your integrand. At the end, you'd calculate the abs of these – and then you'd realize that the $e^{j\ldots}$ factors do not change the abs at all. That's what I answered.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think it would be more useful to everyone if you just submitted your comments as an answer

Comment: they are comments that do not make up an answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: okay i got it.. 
thank you all for your help

Comment: Please "accept" the answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way you can do that.

As the red $i$ is a fixed integer (its randomness is out of context), and the time terms are of the shape $a_k\pi/b_k$ with $a_k$ and $b_k$ integers, you can find a least common multiple, to ensure that all terms have an integer number of periods inside one interval. Then, you can integrate the power of the signal over that interval.

Then, two options can be used:

- compute cosine products, linearize them, and compute the integral
- use orthogonality properties to save a few computations.

If you can show some progress on  your computations, you may get additional hints.